# Creating react component library with submodules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components, package.json, tsconfig

I was trying to develop my on component library like material-ui (https://material-ui.com/). I was trying to reproduce the submodule imports in material-ui like.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

format: @scope/module-name/submodule

I was able to successfully do this in javascript. with the help of exports field in package.json. However doing this in typescript is turning out be a pain. I was successful to export the types of the components i am sending but i then get an error as module cannot be found.

I have tried to find online resources for this but was not able to find anything satisfactory.

I have been stuck on this for more than a week. Any help or online resources will be really helpful.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": [ "src/index.tsx", "src/forms.tsx"],
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.tsx.js",
    "./forms": "./dist/forms.tsx.js"
  },
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "forms": [
        "./dist/forms.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:wbpk": "webpack",
    "build:micro": "microbundle-crl --no-compress --format modern,cjs"
  },
  "author": "sankalp",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "directory-named-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.47.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.10"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                         /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "esnext",                             /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],   /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                             /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                             /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react",                                 /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */
    "declaration": true,                            /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                      /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                              /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                             /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                             /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "src",                               /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                           /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                     /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                      /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                              /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                       /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                  /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                     /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                       /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                    /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                 /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                 /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,        /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                      /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                        /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                      /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                   /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,          /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,            /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                  /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an 'override' modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,  /* Require undeclared properties from index signatures to use element accesses. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "classic",                     /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                             /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                 /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                              /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],         /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                                 /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,           /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                    /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                            /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                               /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                     /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                       /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,              /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: any updates on this